# Python PyQt QtoolbuttonPopup mode

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtoolbar

From what i understood from the internet resources, I could create a Popup menu of `QActions` on the `Qtoolbar` by using `Qtoolbuttonpopup` mode.

So, I created a `QMenu` and added a few `QActions` to it by using `QMenu.addAction`.

After that i have created a `QToolButton` and set the `ToolButtonPopupMode` to `2`. Followed by setting the `QMenu` i have created above as the menu for it by using `.setMenu(QMenu)`

```
    SettingMenu = QtGui.QMenu()
    SettingMenu.addAction(Action1)
    SettingMenu.addAction(Action2)

    SettingButton = QtGui.QToolButton()
    SettingButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap(':/setting.png')))
    SettingButton.ToolButtonPopupMode(2)
    SettingButton.setMenu(SettingMenu)
```

from the above code, i am expecting to have a `Qtoolbutton` on my toolbar and when i click on it, it should pop up a menu with 2 Actions. But when i run the code, all i see is a `Qtoolbutton` on my toolbar but when i click the `Qtoolbutton` it doesn't create any pop up menu.

Am i doing this wrong? How do i create a toolbutton that create a pop up menu of actions upon user click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ToolButtonPopupMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtoolbutton.html#ToolButtonPopupMode-enum) is an [enumerating type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type). All the values in that enum are instances of that type. Because it inherits from int, calling it with an integer returns the same integer. However, you want to set the [popupMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtoolbutton.html#popupMode-prop) property, so use `setPopupMode(2)`.